# How can I see all domains in my SSL certificate made by Certbot?

Tags: certbot

I created a multi domain certificate and forget the domains I included in it.
How can I see them? How can I get this list?

so far I only find a way of how to get the expiration date

```
$ sudo openssl x509 -noout -dates -in /opt/blah-blah/apache2/conf/server.crt
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

found it. The command that lists all certificates and a list of domains for each of them.

```
$ sudo certbot certificates
```